# Simulating a process stuck in a blocking system call

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel

I'm trying to test a behaviour which is hard to reproduce in a controlled environment.

Use case:
Linux system; usually Redhat EL 5 or 6 (we're just starting with RHEL 7 and systemd, so it's currently out of scope).

There're situations where I need to restart a service. The script we use for stopping the service usually works quite well; it sends a SIGTERM to the process, which is designed to handle it; if the process doesn't handle the SIGTERM within a timeout (usually a couple of minutes) the script sends a SIGKILL, then waits a couple minutes more.

The problem is: in some (rare) situations, the process doesn't exit after a SIGKILL; this usually happens when it's badly stuck on a system call, possibly because of a kernel-level issue (corrupt filesystem, or not-working NFS filesystem, or something equally bad requiring manual intervention).

A bug arose when the script didn't realize that the "old" process hadn't actually exited and started a new process while the old was still running; we're fixing this with a stronger locking system (so that at least the new process doesn't start if the old is running), but **I find it difficult to test the whole thing** because I haven't found a way to simulate an hard-stuck process.

So, the question is:

**How can I manually simulate a process that doesn't exit when sending a SIGKILL to it, even as a privileged user?**

Comment: Have you checked the syslog and looked for processes in un-interruptable or blocked state possibly stuck doing I/O.

Comment: @askb I'm not asking "why the process is stuck". I can handle that, there's usually an hard failure the kernel can't cope with. I want to make my service script better, so I'm asking "how can I block a process in an uninterruptible syscall" in order to perform my testing.

Answer (score 7):

If your process are stuck doing I/O, You can simulate your situation in this way:

```
lvcreate -n lvtest -L 2G vgtest
mkfs.ext3 -m0 /dev/vgtest/lvtest
mount /dev/vgtest/lvtest /mnt
dmsetup suspend /dev/vgtest/lvtest && dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/file.img bs=1M count=2048 &
```

In this way the dd process will stuck waiting for IO and will ignore every signal, I know the signals aren't ignore in the latest kernel when processes are waiting for IO on nfs filesystem.

Comment: Nice method. Thanks. But the last command could will create a bash process firstly, and the `dd` command can not be waited in current bash session.

Answer (score 1):

Well... How about just not sending SIGKILL? So your env will behave like it was sent, but the process didn't quit.

Answer (score 1):

Once a proces is in "D" state (or TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE) in a kernel code path where the execution can not be interrupted while a task is processed, which means sending any signals to the process would not be useful and would be ignored.

This can be caused due to device driver getting too many interrupts from the hardware, getting too many incoming network packets, data from NIC firmware or blocked on a HDD performing I/O. Normally if this happens very quickly and threads remain in this state for very short span of time.

Therefore what you need to be doing is look at the syslog and sar reports during the time when the process was stuck in D-state. If you find stack traces in the log, try to search kernel.bugzilla.org for similar issues or seek support from the Linux vendor.

Answer (score 0):

I would code the opposite way. Have your server process write its pid in e.g. `/var/run/yourserver.pid` (this is common practice). Have the starting script read that file and test that the process does not exist e.g. with `kill` of signal 0, or with

```
yourserver_pid=$(cat /var/run/yourserver.pid)
if [ -f /proc/$yourserver_pid/exe ]; then
```

<sup>You could improve that by `readlink /proc/$yourserver_pid/exe` and comparing that to `/usr/bin/yourserver`</sup>

BTW, having a process still alive a few seconds after a `SIGKILL` is a serious situation (the common case when it could happen is if the process is stuck in a `D` state, waiting for some NFS server), and you probably should detect and syslog it (e.g. with `logger` in your script).

I also would try to first send `SIGTERM`, wait a few seconds, send `SIGQUIT`, wait a few seconds, and at last send `SIGKILL` and only a few seconds later test that the server process has gone

Answer (score 0):

> A bug arose when the script didn't realize that the "old" process hadn't actually exited and started a new process while the old was still running;

This is the bug in the OS/kernel level, not in your service script. The situation is rare and is hard to simulate because the [OS is supposed to kill the process when SIGKILL signal happens](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html). So I guess your goal is to let your script work well under a buggy kernel. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach gdb to the process, SIGKILL won't remove such process from processlist but it will flag it as zombie, which might still be acceptable for your purpose.

```
void@tahr:~$ ping 8.8.8.8 > /tmp/ping.log &
[1] 3770
void@tahr:~$ ps 3770
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
3770 pts/13   S      0:00 ping 8.8.8.8

void@tahr:~$ sudo gdb -p 3770
...
(gdb)
```

Other terminal

```
void@tahr:~$ ps 3770 
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
3770 pts/13   t      0:00 ping 8.8.8.8

sudo kill -9 3770
...
void@tahr:~$ ps 3770
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
3770 pts/13   Z      0:00 [ping] <defunct>
```

First terminal again

```
(gdb) quit
```